# Почему встроенный метод работает в 2.5 раза быстрее чем мой бинарный поиск?

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск, производительность

Читаю "Грокаем алгоритмы" и сразу возник вопрос про бинарный поиск. Написал код для проверки за сколько времени найдет элемент в списке встроенный метод list.index и за сколько находит бинарный поиск. И вот собственно мой вопрос: почему встроенный метод работает в 2.5 раза быстрее чем бинарный поиск? Что то не так с моим кодом? Или встроенный метод имеет более быстрый алгоритм (а если так, то на каком алгоритме он реализован?)? В общем помогите разобраться.

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

#декоратор бенчмарк
def bench(func):
    def wrapper():
        start = time.time()
        func()
        end = time.time()
        print('{}'.format(end - start))
    return wrapper

#генерируем список
def gen_list():
    big_list = []
    x = 1
    while len(big_list) != 10000000:
        big_list.append(x)
        x += 1
    return big_list

#время нахождение методом индекс
@bench
def search_index():
    big_list = gen_list()
    dx = big_list.index(5000001)
    return dx

#время нахождения бинарным поиском
@bench
def binary_search():
    low = 0
    high = len(gen_list()) - 1
    l = list(gen_list())

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)
        guess = l[mid]
        if guess == 5000001:
            return mid
        elif guess > 5000001:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None


def main():
    print('')
    print('простой поиск по индексу:')
    search_index()
    print('*' * 20)
    print('бинарный поиск:')
    binary_search()

main()
```

Comment: `mid = (low + high)` — а где деление на 2?

Comment: Ещё вы 2 раза создаёте список

Comment: Самое очевидное — потому что list.index написан не на питоне. Ну а остальное уже Harry рассказал

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ну, как минимум, зачем вы дважды генерируете список?

```
high = len(gen_list()) - 1
l = list(gen_list())
```

У меня было 2.1 против 4.8 секунды. После замены на

```
big_list = gen_list()
high = len(big_list) - 1
l = list(big_list)
```

Стало 2.1 на 2.9. Хорошо бы вынести генерацию из бенчмарка вообще - но это вы уж сами...

Ну, а потом, надо учесть, что встроенный поиск сделан не на Python, что уже несколько поднимает скорость, да он и не выполняет никакой арифметики, только сравнение - а ваш поиск написан на самом Python, не оптимален, etc etc...

А после того, как исправил замеченное @AlexeyTen (сам я, увы, не обратил внимания...) -

```
mid = (low + high)//2
```

то соотношение стало 2.1 к 2.0 в пользу бинарного поиска.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А теперь меня интересует, почему бинарный поиск оказывается быстрее "встроенного" поиска в списках?) Типо вот вам поиск из коробки, но если хотите быстрее, допишите сами 5 строчек самого простого алгоритма?!

Comment: Поиск из коробки работает с неупорядоченными списками. А бинарный - только с упорядоченными. Я не спец в Python, но, думаю, в нем тоже есть какой-то встроенный бинарный поиск - для применения, когда известна упорядоченность массива.

Comment: Вынес генерацию из бенчмарка и бинарный поиск опять стал дольше. :/

Comment: @DreamSeller значит вы опять измеряете неправильно https://ideone.com/AFxdOG

Comment: @extrn https://pastebin.com/V7DUpye5 что я сделал не так?

Comment: @DreamSeller например это `l = list(big_list)`.

Comment: @extrn ок, исправил на bb = big_list и бинарный поиск стал быстрее. Почему так? Я же не создавал новый список. А лишь просто явно указал (хз зачем) что это список.

Comment: @DreamSeller `list` это конструктор списка, он конструирует список из переданной ему последовательности. В вашем случае он создал список из списка, т.е. сделал неглубокую копию.